# Kafka Streams KeyValueStore retention.bytes

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a funny behaviour with KeyValueStore and I have some assumption to explain it, may be you can tell I am right or wrong...

I configured a state store like the following

```
Map<String, String> storeConfig = new HashMap<>();
storeConfig.put(TopicConfig.RETENTION_MS_CONFIG, TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(30));
storeConfig.put(TopicConfig.CLEANUP_POLICY_CONFIG, "compact,delete");

StoreBuilder store1 = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
   Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("STORE1"),
   Serdes.String(),
   Serdes.String()
);

streamsBuilder.addStateStore(store1.withLoggingEnabled(storeConfig));
```

with this configuration, I am expecting a dataset older then 30 Days will disappear but I am observing something completely different.

When I look to the rockdb directory of the store, every 14451 bytes it rolls the file and I have a such structure in the directory

```
14451  1. Oct 19:00 LOG
14181 30. Sep 15:59 LOG.old.1569854012833395
14451 30. Sep 17:40 LOG.old.1569918431235734
14451  1. Oct 11:05 LOG.old.1569949239434224
```

It seems instead of realising retention over 30 days that is configured it also realises over the file size.

I found on the internet that there is also the parameter Topic.RETENTION_BYTES_CONFIG 'retention.bytes', do I also have to configure this parameter, so my Data is visible during the retention and not deleted because of the file size (I know I have value for my key but I can't access it after this phenomena occurs)...

Thx for answers..

Answer (score 1):

Internally, `KeyValueStores` use RocksDB, and RocksDB uses a so-called LSM-Tree (Log-Structured-Merged-Tree) internally, and it creates many smaller segments that are later combined into larger segments. After this "compaction" step, the smaller segment files can be deleted, because the data is copied into larger segment files. Hence, there is nothing to worry about.

Furthermore, `Topic.RETENTION_MS_CONFIG` is a topic configuration and is not related to the local store of a Kafka Streams application. Furthermore, a `KeyValueStore` will retain data forever, until explicitly deleted via a "tombstone" message. Hence, if you set a retention time for the underlying changelog topic, the data might be deleted in the topic, but not in the local store.

If you want to apply a retention time to a local store, you cannot use a `KevValueStore`, but you could use `WindowedStore` that supports a retention time.

Comment: Weird thing, the values for Keys are disappearing without tombstone messages....May be while I am using as Cleanup policy 'compact,delete' I will try to create a repeatable test may be I can say more about it...

Comment: Topic compaction policy should not apply to the store itself. Of course, if you rebuild the store from the changelog, deleted keys would not be recovered.

Comment: Great answer. Are there any plans for supporting a retention time in a key-value store? Introducing windowing only to delete old data seems to be more than needed. The semantics would be to remove all data that has not been updated for the last X days, hours, minutes, etc.

Comment: This seems to be related: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4212

Comment: And this also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4273

Comment: `Are there any plans for supporting a retention time in a key-value store?` No at the moment. -- `Introducing windowing only to delete old data seems to be more than needed.` Not really, because a WindowedStore is just a KV-store with retention time. -- And yes, there are feature request tickets, but it's unclear if/when they might get picked up.